# Parse push not working on updating existing android app

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

After updating my app self hosted parse server,it is no longer updating the current installation to the Parse Server. This leaves my App unable to receive push notifications.

**On a fresh installation everything works fine**. But when **updating** the existing application it is not working. ie the installation table not updating.

i added the gcm sender id in the manifest also added the following lines in the application class

```
ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
parseInstallation.put("GCMSenderId","My Sender ID");
parseInstallation.saveInBackground();
```

Please help me to to solve the problem on updating existing app?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use parse.com
This project is closed
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: I dnt use parse.com. I created the new self hosted the parse instance.